# Есть ли какие-либо способы заработка для пользователей в рамках данного сайта?

Tags: обсуждение

На сайте много профессионалов, а также тех, кто стремится ими стать. Они решают и помогают решать много самых разных задач, которые возникают у пользователей, задающих вопросы на этом сайте.

В связи с этим возникает вопрос, а можно ли это дело каким-либо образом монетизировать для пользователей "в рамках текущей политики" конечно же? Если да, т.е. если это напрямую не запрещено, то как?

Предлагаю поразмыслить над этим.

P.S. Навеяно текущим активным обсуждением решения администрации о лишении владельцев чата этого звания, так как на это у обсуждающих ушёл не один десяток человеко-часов, которые они могли бы использовать в рамках более полезного (прибыльного) для них дела.

Comment: напрямую - никак

Comment: Надо выпустить свою криптовалюту! `SOin`! Сразу все разбогатеем! =)))

Comment: даёшь конкурсы с вознаграждением в валюте. зачем нам 50 репы, дайте 50 у.е. </sarcasm>

Comment: мне не нравится эта идея, для монетизации есть фриланс биржи

Comment: @ЮрийСПб вот вы шутите, а менеджеры уже в блокнотики записали...

Comment: @FoggyFinder вы её не поняли, суть не в ответах за деньги, ибо это выходит за "рамки данного сайта", как сказано в заголовке.

Comment: Ваши ответы и вопросы — это очень превосходное резюме. Особенно для соискания руководящих должностей (старший инженер и лидер команды):  по вашим ответам виден не только ваши технические знания, но и умение обучать других, без чего старшим инженером не стать.

Comment: Есть, конечно! У нас же есть Jobs на англосайте.

Comment: @edem возможно что и не понял, если суть не в том, чтобы получать деньги за ответы, то в чем она?

Comment: если для вас " ответы за деньги" выходит за "рамки данного сайта", то что вы имеете ввиду? Что в вашем понимании "заработок" и как очерчены "рамки сайта"? О чём вообще ваш вопрос? Какой вы ответ ожидали?

Comment: @FoggyFinder в том, чтобы получать доход от активности на сайте, не изменяя текущие пользовательские соглашения и другие правила сети SE.

Comment: @jfs ну функционал оплаты ответов не предусмотрен правилами сети SE, насколько мне известно. Вопрос в том, есть ли другие способы, которые этим правилам не противоречат, и которые позволят получать доход от пользования данными сайтами.

Comment: @edem тем не менее это все равно сводится к ответам за деньги, что приведет к тому, что качество ответов уменьшится в разы

Comment: @FoggyFinder чем обоснован такой вывод про качество?

Comment: @edem если будет зависимость получаемой суммы от количества ответов, то можно будет завести дополнительный аккаунт (или сразу несколько) для простых вопросов или отвечать на все вопросы подряд парой строчек. Если будет зависимость от количества плюсов - организовывается группа, которая занимается накруткой для своих аккаунтов. Пока сайт держится на энтузиазме мало кому в голову придет заниматься подобной ерундой, но как только речь пойдет о деньгах все поменяется.

Comment: @FoggyFinder да, есть такая опасность, но и сейчас, без денег, есть такие "гонщики" за репой. В этом плане здесь ничего нового.

Comment: @edem со временем "гонщики за репой" "спалятся" и тем больше будет их огорчение чем выше будет накрученная репутация. Кроме этого, на мой взгляд, со временем им может надоесть это бесполезное занятие. P.S.: подразумеваются накрутчики.

Comment: Предлагаю денежно вознаграждать достигших определённого количества репутации. Скажем, миллион ;).

Comment: Да нет, гонщики за репой никуда не денутся. Но и сайту они пока не вредят. А людям помогают, а таким образом и на пользу сообщества работают. Возможно, не идеальным, но тоже полезным образом.

Answer (score 7):

В текущем [соглашении](https://stackexchange.com/legal) не обсуждаются какие бы там ни было денежные отношения между участниками. Stack Overflow как компания оказывает, среди прочего, платные услуги пользователям. А других формальных предписаний, сколько-нибудь касающихся дела, нет.

Поэтому это вопрос больше про взаимодействие между участниками и про то, чем они считают и не считают Stack Overflow.

---

Я сомневаюсь, что такое сколько-нибудь часто случается даже в частном порядке. Финансы в сообществе Stack Overflow никогда не имели серьёзного влияния:

- Модель работы и правила SO для всех, даже тех, кто с финансами. На хороший вопрос ответят, если есть кому. А плохой вопрос осудят.
- Материальная награда за ответ не является типичным явлением на сайте, поэтому и отвечающих, рассчитывающих на неё и не работающих без неё, тут практически нет. Предположительно, спрос рождает предложение. Спроса не обнаружено.
- Желающие могут размещать у себя в профилях кнопки для перечисления им пожертвований. Но судя по [шутке с кислой миной](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/39083390#39083390) от [весьма популярного участника](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/191482/), меценатов-вопрошающих на сайте тоже исчезающе мало. А кроме как у него, я больше ни у кого (на ru.SO) таких кнопок/ссылок не припоминаю.

---

Теоретически, если появится критическая масса до материального благодарных читателей, чтобы пожертвования стали сколько-нибудь массовым явлением... что-то может пойти хорошо, что-то наоборот, плохо.

- На SO может возникнуть больше заинтересованных авторов ответов, которые ранее проходили мимо, не видя для себя смысла в участии. Почему бы и нет? Ответы за материальное вознаграждение, скорее всего, будут неразличимы среди остальных, они точно так же будут публичными, будут приносить пользу случайным людям.
- Требовать денег за ответ, скорее всего, будет по-прежнему считаться крайне грубым/невежливым. Потому что если это станет нормой, SO станет фриланс-биржей и расфокусируется от своего первичного формата Q&A. Так что насаждать эту норму, удерживающую фокус SO, могут начать и сверху, если возникнет необходимость.

---

*Это всё моё личное мнение по вопросу. Надумаю ещё чего — напишу.*

Comment: stack overflow [среди прочего] практически заменил сервис, который мусорил гугл-результаты, где вопросы/ответы на платной основе были¶ Попытаться в слепую смешивать волонтёрскую работу и работу за денежное вознаграждение опасно. Можно остаться ни с тем ни с другим. Мотивация совершенно разная.  Пара ссылок для затравки: http://www.nytimes.com/2005/05/15/books/chapters/freakonomics.html?referer=http://freakonomics.com/2013/10/23/what-makes-people-do-what-they-do/ и https://josephnoone.com/2016/01/16/autonomy-mastery-and-purpose-3-keys-to-motivating-employees/

Comment: @jfs историческая справка, круто. Мне кажется, это достойно быть в собственном ответе. Вопрос-то дискуссионный.

Comment: автор вопроса уже знает, что в рамках stack overflow сайта всё бесплатно для обычных пользователей. Какой ответ, кроме простого "нет" ожидается — не ясно. Обсуждать почему именно так — это слишком обширный вопрос (возможны и другие рабочие [коммерческие модели](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79435/137096)). Уравнивать "полезное" и "прибыльное" вообще токсично в рамках сайта, построенного на добровольцах (подмена социальной инициативы денежной).

Comment: @jfs хотя бы уже за те ссылки, которые вы привели в комментариях, уже стоило задавать этот вопрос.

Answer (score 4):

Считаю, что затея с "монетизацией" ответов изначально бесперспективна.

Те, кто готов платить и зарабатывать, обычно сразу идут на "биржи фрилансеров" и прочие "коммерческие" сайты. На бесплатных ресурсах в основном обитают скорее люди увлечённые программированием. Немало и тех кто просто, мягко выражаясь, "не может себе позволить" платные услуги.

Так что "критическую массу до материального благодарных читателей", о которой высказались ранее, думаю, придётся ждать очень долго.

Да и с текущим форматом сайта подобное поведение трудно совместимо.

Правда, на одном энтузиазме тоже далеко не уедешь.

Время, потраченное на ответ, а иногда и дополнительное обсуждение, можно было бы использовать и для других, не менее интересных занятий. Кроме того, на жизнь, в частности интернет, тоже нужно заработать.

Всё это так или иначе влияет на активность многих участников.

Comment: *"Те, кто готов платить и зарабатывать, обычно сразу идут на "биржи фрилансеров" и прочие "коммерческие" сайты."* -- да, я примерно это и имел в виду под "чем они считают и не считают Stack Overflow". Спасибо что развернули мысль в важном направлении.